# Kubernetes installation in 3 node setup

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to install kubernetes using kubeadm in 3 node VM setup based on Ubuntu 16.04 VMs where 1 VM acts as Master while 2 VMs acts as Slave nodes running in pods.

I am following the steps mentioned in

https://gist.github.com/ruanbekker/38a38aea5f325f7fa4a19e795ef4f0d0

https://www.mirantis.com/blog/how-install-kubernetes-kubeadm/

So on master node the moment I run Kubeadm init command it gets stuck saying pulling the control images. Am I missing any steps to properly start kubernetes ? If there is any link or document which explains how to successfully install atleast a 3 node cluster would be great.

```
ipi@mm202:~$ sudo apt-get install -y kubelet kubeadm kubectl kubernetes-cni
[sudo] password for ipi: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
kubeadm is already the newest version (1.10.4-00).
kubectl is already the newest version (1.10.4-00).
kubelet is already the newest version (1.10.4-00).
kubernetes-cni is already the newest version (0.6.0-00).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  bridge-utils containerd linux-headers-4.13.0-36 linux-headers-4.13.0-36-generic linux-image-4.13.0-36-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-127-generic linux-image-extra-4.13.0-36-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-127-generic pigz
  runc ubuntu-fan
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
ipi@mm202:~$ sudo kubeadm init
[init] Using Kubernetes version: v1.10.4
[init] Using Authorization modes: [Node RBAC]
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks.
    [WARNING FileExisting-crictl]: crictl not found in system path
Suggestion: go get github.com/kubernetes-incubator/cri-tools/cmd/crictl
[certificates] Generated ca certificate and key.
[certificates] Generated apiserver certificate and key.
[certificates] apiserver serving cert is signed for DNS names [mm202 kubernetes kubernetes.default kubernetes.default.svc kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local] and IPs [10.96.0.1 10.10.26.148]
[certificates] Generated apiserver-kubelet-client certificate and key.
[certificates] Generated sa key and public key.
[certificates] Generated front-proxy-ca certificate and key.
[certificates] Generated front-proxy-client certificate and key.
[certificates] Generated etcd/ca certificate and key.
[certificates] Generated etcd/server certificate and key.
[certificates] etcd/server serving cert is signed for DNS names [localhost] and IPs [127.0.0.1]
[certificates] Generated etcd/peer certificate and key.
[certificates] etcd/peer serving cert is signed for DNS names [mm202] and IPs [10.10.26.148]
[certificates] Generated etcd/healthcheck-client certificate and key.
[certificates] Generated apiserver-etcd-client certificate and key.
[certificates] Valid certificates and keys now exist in "/etc/kubernetes/pki"
[kubeconfig] Wrote KubeConfig file to disk: "/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf"
[kubeconfig] Wrote KubeConfig file to disk: "/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf"
[kubeconfig] Wrote KubeConfig file to disk: "/etc/kubernetes/controller-manager.conf"
[kubeconfig] Wrote KubeConfig file to disk: "/etc/kubernetes/scheduler.conf"
[controlplane] Wrote Static Pod manifest for component kube-apiserver to "/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml"
[controlplane] Wrote Static Pod manifest for component kube-controller-manager to "/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-controller-manager.yaml"
[controlplane] Wrote Static Pod manifest for component kube-scheduler to "/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-scheduler.yaml"
[etcd] Wrote Static Pod manifest for a local etcd instance to "/etc/kubernetes/manifests/etcd.yaml"
[init] Waiting for the kubelet to boot up the control plane as Static Pods from directory "/etc/kubernetes/manifests".
[init] This might take a minute or longer if the control plane images have to be pulled.
```

If i execute below kubectl command I can see that client is not reachable

```
ipi@mm202:~$ sudo kubectl version 
[sudo] password for ipi: 
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"10", GitVersion:"v1.10.4", GitCommit:"5ca598b4ba5abb89bb773071ce452e33fb66339d", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-06-06T08:13:03Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
The connection to the server 10.10.26.148:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
ipi@mm202:~$
```

***Updated**

```
ipi@mm202:~$ sudo docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                        COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                        PORTS               NAMES
5e3826260751        52920ad46f5b                 "etcd --client-cer..."   26 seconds ago      Exited (1) 25 seconds ago                         k8s_etcd_etcd-mm202_kube-system_cf966237db9a791ace9f5788e9f4fd9a_2
0366ea0ef627        afdd56622af3                 "kube-apiserver --..."   30 seconds ago      Exited (255) 17 seconds ago                       k8s_kube-apiserver_kube-apiserver-mm202_kube-system_980acadbdc97171782e300778c16008b_1
57afc9d65f97        1a24f5586598                 "kube-controller-m..."   43 seconds ago      Up 42 seconds                                     k8s_kube-controller-manager_kube-controller-manager-mm202_kube-system_84183acd85a9e65994a24ce3c23c9533_0
5cda05f323c3        6fffbea311f0                 "kube-scheduler --..."   43 seconds ago      Up 42 seconds                                     k8s_kube-scheduler_kube-scheduler-mm202_kube-system_a45cd09c7a02c8a7e64580248df4b50d_0
63f974dbea93        k8s.gcr.io/pause-amd64:3.1   "/pause"                 43 seconds ago      Up 42 seconds                                     k8s_POD_kube-controller-manager-mm202_kube-system_84183acd85a9e65994a24ce3c23c9533_0
dec4a2a3c6ca        k8s.gcr.io/pause-amd64:3.1   "/pause"                 43 seconds ago      Up 42 seconds                                     k8s_POD_kube-apiserver-mm202_kube-system_980acadbdc97171782e300778c16008b_0
882cb2b1011e        k8s.gcr.io/pause-amd64:3.1   "/pause"                 43 seconds ago      Up 42 seconds                                     k8s_POD_etcd-mm202_kube-system_cf966237db9a791ace9f5788e9f4fd9a_0
583fb3bbae8d        k8s.gcr.io/pause-amd64:3.1   "/pause"                 43 seconds ago      Up 42 seconds                                     k8s_POD_kube-scheduler-mm202_kube-system_a45cd09c7a02c8a7e64580248df4b50d_0
28ba22a1f54e        hello-world                  "/hello"                 12 days ago         Exited (0) 12 days ago                            modest_kilby
ipi@mm202:~$
```

Comment: Does that machine use an HTTP proxy?

Comment: What is the output of `docker ps -a` and `journalctl -xe --lines=500`?

Comment: Just follow the instruction for master:
`kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr 192.168.0.0/16 --service-cidr 10.96.0.0/12 --service-dns-domain "k8s" --apiserver-advertise-address $(ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet addr'| cut -d':' -f2 | awk '{print $1}')`

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel - No I havent got any HTTP proxy. I have updated the question with the requested information

Comment: @NickRak - Tried exactly the same command as you have mentioned and still in the same state

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel - I can see some serious failures when I try Journalctl command but I am not sure how to place that output down in stackoverflow

Comment: `Exited (1) 25 seconds ago` is very, very bad news, as is its `Exited (255)` friend -- but more or less to-be-expected since without `etcd`, few positive things happen from there. You'd want to `docker logs 5e3826260751` to see what etcd is angry about, and/or `docker logs 0366ea0ef627`. As for "how to place that output in stackoverflow," you can use pastebin or just include the text exactly as you did with the output of `docker ps`, since I don't know if there is any post body limit

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel - Thanks for the help. I have created the link containing logs for the requested information - https://pastebin.com/D8L6PAPA

Comment: Where did `10.10.27.154` come from in `etcdmain: listen tcp 10.10.27.154:2380`, since the only other `10.10` address in the logs is `10.10.26.148`? Similar question about what the output is of `$(ifconfig ens3 | grep 'inet addr'| cut -d':' -f2 | awk '{print $1}')`?

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel - ens3      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:cc:01:6b  
          inet addr:10.10.26.148  Bcast:10.10.26.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::6a1f:3ffc:8ad3:4b20/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:131053 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:14910 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:15660959 (15.6 MB)  TX bytes:5106763 (5.1 MB)

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel - Even I am confused now why it is trying to reach 10.10.27.154. Is there any config file where it is mentioned or it takes this value via some discovery mechanism ?

Comment: _Is there any config file where it is mentioned_ unfortunately, there could be many of them; maybe `grep -rl 10.10.27.154 /etc` and see what surfaces. You'll want to also check the docker container configs, which `docker inspect $(docker ps -aq) | jq . | grep 10.10.27.154` will (rather simplistically) do. As for the discovery, _possible_ but I would expect a discovered address to be in the `Service` CIDR range, 10.96

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel - Not sure how but I was suspecting etcd was getting wrong ipaddress i.e. 10.10.27.154. I Just changed the init command as sudo kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr 192.168.0.0/16 --apiserver-advertise-address 10.10.26.148 and now it works fine - https://pastebin.com/s0dygAcY. So question is what is i need to find what does "-service-cidr " and "--service-dns-domain" do

Comment: `service-cidr` is the address space in which "permanent" IPs live in kubernetes, in contrast to the Pod IPs which are ephemeral and "meaningless". You typically would not want Service and Pod IPs to overlap, if for no other reason than being able to tell them apart quickly; `service-dns-domain` is *typically* `svc.cluster.local` but `.local` is a pseudo-reserved top-level domain, so if you wanted to use something else (`svc.cluster.k8s` or whatever) that would be the place to adjust, just be careful because I think everyone uses the default (for good or bad)

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel - It works even fine if I try with sudo kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr 192.168.0.0/16 --service-cidr 10.96.0.0/12 --service-dns-domain "k8s" --apiserver-advertise-address 10.10.26.148. Thanks Matthew for all your help and time

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel - Please do suggest any training or guides which would help to understand some of the Kubernetes internals. I do agree we need to go through the code for the same but any of the above would help to speed up the process :)

Comment: _Please do suggest any training or guides which would help to understand some of the Kubernetes internals_ [Kubernetes the Hard Way](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way#readme) is a well regarded one, but I learned from [Kubernetes on CoreOS](https://github.com/coreos/coreos-kubernetes/tree/v0.4.0/multi-node/vagrant) because it is shell, `docker`, an immutable operating system, and you can destroy local vagrant boxes over and over. Be cautious that `0.4.0` is the last before they switched to the `rkt` mind-poison

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel - Thanks for the suggestions .. I will make sure to keep away from the mind-poison :)